# sort a list of django models by specific fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a list of Django objects, all from the same class and those objects are not saved in the DB. 
I want to sort the list (again, a list of models) by a specific field in that class.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list.sort#list.sort) with a `key` function????

Comment: you mean the python sort?

Comment: If they're not saved in the db, that's the only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so this is what I did and it worked for me:

list_of_models = sorted(list_of_models , key = lambda x: x.object.time)